# Pandas erratically returning TypeError cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [310] of <class 'int'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a really strange problem with pandas - I'm trying to extract a column of values from a dataframe for downstream analysis.  The script I have written iterates over many files at a time to do this.  Each file was created using the same command on bam-readcounts and contains read depth data for a DNA sequencing run.

Sometimes, it works like a dream and returns everything I need it to return, others I get an error message:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [310] of <class 'int'>
```

The column definitely contains integers - I've tried running the script with floats and with str just to be sure.

I've even had instances where I've analysed the same set of files a few minutes apart without changing the code of my script and had pandas return the error message.  I've had instances where I've analysed two batches of files created at the same time with bam-headcount and had it return the error message on one batch, but not the other.

The relevant piece of code is:

```
col_names = ['Col_' + str(i) for i in range(1, max_col_nr)]

df = pd.read_csv(myFile, sep = '\t', names = col_names)
df2 = df.set_index("Col_2", drop = False)
df3 = (df2.loc[310:400,"Col_4"])
US_Av = (int(round(df4.mean())))
```

I've never had a situation like this where the same bit of code changes its behaviour on run to run and if anyone has any advice I would be extremely grateful.  It is driving me slightly insane.

Example data for reference below.  It is the 4th column I'm trying to get the average for.

```
GRIN2A  280 A   169     
GRIN2A  281 C   169 
GRIN2A  282 C   172
GRIN2A  283 T   171
```

Comment: Are all the files encoded the same? And do they all have the same line endings?

Comment: Yeah, they were made at the same time using bam-headcount, which crates a tab delimited table of data from a genomic alignment file.

I have three folders of files, each was originally aligned to the reference sequence with a different aligner (bwa-ont, minimap2 and ngmlr).  The nglmrs are processing fine, but the other two aren't.  

Thing is... the minimap2s processed fine earlier today.  Then they didn't, then they did again, now they don't.  I haven't altered the script running in any way.

Comment: Hmm... okay, I've set a print (file) near the line of code causing the error.  The iterator is going through some of the files with no problem then struggling to do the operation with a couple in each folder.  I can't find any common issue between the files it's struggling with (or indeed, between the problem files and the others).  Removing the files from the folders fixes the problem, but I am loosing a couple of files worth of data each time.

Interested to know if anyone else has ever had this - will leave the question open for now as I'm a little intrigued.

Comment: Have you specifically set the `dtype` of `Col_2`? I don't see that anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've got it - you were on the right lines with dtype.  In the files which failed, pandas was wrongly labelling the columns.  The correct result for pd should be

```
df =
      Col_1  Col_2 Col_3  Col_4  
0    GRIN2A    280     A     44   
1    GRIN2A    281     C     44   
2    GRIN2A    282     C     44
```

For some files, the same code results in

```
df =
        Col_1 Col_2  Col_3
GRIN2A    280     A     46
GRIN2A    281     A     46
GRIN2A    282     A     46
```

This meant that, for the files where this happened, the indexed Col_2 was str rather than int, resulting in the error message.

I still can't work out for the life of me why pandas is mis-heading the columns in some files, but not others (2 or 3 per iteration over 300 files).  The files are identically formatted and created by running the same bam-readcount iterator over my sorted bam files.

The code including pandas is also run by an iterator, so will be identical for every file.

I can work around using something along the lines of...

```
if Col2 is (int): 
elif Col1 is (int):
```

A bit clumsy and doesn't solve the underlying issue, but at least I won't loose the data in the erroneously headed files.  If anyone has any ideas why this may be happening I'd love to hear comments.

Thank you for the help RCA

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly set `dtypes` in a few ways, which will let you avoid if statements.

The first is the set the types as you read the files, like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myFile,
                 sep = '\t',
                 names = col_names,
                 dtype = {<column name>: np.int32, ...}) # note that you'll need numpy imported
```

This obviously only works if you know ahead of time what types your columns are. The documentation for [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) has more information - you can also set just some of the columns, or tell pandas to skip interpretation for the whole file (which you'd want to do if you try the following options).

The next option is to use [`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), which will coerce the series before you make it the index. This is probably the easiest way to do it.

```
df = pd.read_csv(myFile, sep = '\t', names = col_names)
df["Col_2"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Col_2"])
df2 = df.set_index("Col_2", drop = False)
df3 = (df2.loc[310:400,"Col_4"])
US_Av = (int(round(df4.mean())))
```

Then, finally, the one-line version:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myFile, sep = '\t', names = col_names)
df2 = df.set_index(df.Col_2.as_type(int), drop = False)
df3 = (df2.loc[310:400,"Col_4"])
US_Av = (int(round(df4.mean())))
```